# d3.pack() transitions update

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, transition, circle-pack

I am trying to apply a transition over a d3.pack().

Please check http://bl.ocks.org/3263043

I want to symbolize by a new paremeter, but when applying transitions, 
the new circles and its parents don't keep the structural 'harmony' anymore (some children circles are not contained anymore by its parents).

I apply the new value via...

```
pack.value(function(d) {
    return gScale(d.new_parameter)
    })
```

Reconstruct the package...

```
svg.data([json]).selectAll("g.node").data(pack.nodes)
```

append new nodes (which should be already correctly positioned with its parents) and finally make a circle transition (its new radius should be proportional to the new pack, so I don't understand where the error is...)

Any idea or reference?

Comment: It appears that you are transitioning the radius of the circle elements, but are not transitioning the x and y position of those elements

Comment: yes Josh, you are right.Thanks. I finally managed to get it work! http://bl.ocks.org/3263043

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to get it work. You can check the result at http://bl.ocks.org/3263043

The problem was, that the nodes where not transitioned.